# Duplications Users in my application chat android

Tags: java, android

"I design a chat application for android I have a problem with my code, what happens is that its duplicate users, please how to correct my code ???"

here is the code in question please help me repair this duplication of user, what is wrong? please help me

```
    package com.developer.fireone.finga.Fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;

import com.developer.fireone.finga.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Adapter.UserChatAdapter;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Model.Chat;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Model.ChatList;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Model.User;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.Notifications.Token;
import com.developer.fireone.finga.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private UserChatAdapter userChatAdapter;

    private List <User> mUsers, newUserArrayList;

    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    private List<String> usersList;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);


        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        usersList= new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                usersList.clear();
             for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                 Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                 if(chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())) {
                     usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                 }

                 if(chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())) {
                     usersList.add(chat.getSender());
                 }

             }

                readChats();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        updateToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

        return view;
    }

    private void readChats() {

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
//Create a new list object
        newUserArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                mUsers.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for(String id : usersList){
                        if(user.getId().equals(id)){
                            if(mUsers.size() != 0){
                                for(User user1 : mUsers){
                                    if(!user.getId().equals(user1.getId())){
                                        newUserArrayList.add(user);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                newUserArrayList.add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                userChatAdapter = new UserChatAdapter(getContext(), newUserArrayList, true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userChatAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

image to the duplication :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQxMG.png)
image firebase :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEYu8.png)
I want a user to appear in the chat box once when sending or receiving a message

Comment: Ok, what are you trying to achive within the for(String id: UserList) loop?

Comment: I want to help you brother, but you have to help me understand your code first! You debbuged your code already?? it seems a problem inside the OnDataChange, I didn`t understand what you`re trying to do there, show more things, like your firebase structure, it's pretty hard to figure out whats happening with so little information, I'm sorry